# soup.find does not work in cloud function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-cloud-functions

I have a python script which is working very well on my local machine but when I copy it to cloud function it does not work anymore. The problem is this soup.find.
I scraped a page which has  and I want to get the value here as Sessions token. I use

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
session_token = soup.find('input')['value']
```

which is working fine on my local machine but in cloud function it gives me below error

```
Output  Complete
$
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

logs:
`line 30, in client_main session_token = soup.find('input')['value'] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: What site are you trying to reach? Are there any cookies you are not passing along?

Comment: The site is for Jamf to get the logs. Can it be the case? First I authenticate and then I scrape the page and the script works very well on my local machine

Comment: how do u auth? please, provide as much code as you can for us to understand

Comment: Have you enabled billing for the Cloud Function? Cloud Functions cannot make external network requests until billing is enabled.